# Can Tabulator autocomplete be set up per cell? Not column?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tabulator

I need to have have two autocompletes in my Tabulator definition. A user will select an employee - first autocomplete - then when he moves to select a contract - second column the autocomplete must be linked to the value selected in the first column.

[image]

To my knowledge [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/edit#edit-builtin) does not have such feature. So I was thinking that upon clicking the "contract" cell that column definition - autocomplete definition - would be updated. I cannot make it work because the function `updateDefinition` is [buggy](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3528). It creates new column instead of updating its definition.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/us79t2hj/49/)

```
  table.on("cellEditing", function(cell){
        //e - the click event object
        //cell - cell component
       updateTitle(cell)
})
table.on("cellClick", function(e, cell){
  updateTitle(cell)
})

function updateTitle(cell){
  var field = cell.getField()
  if (field == "contract" || field =="id"){
    var column = cell.getColumn()
    var name = cell.getRow().getData().name
    console.log(field)   
    console.log(name)
    column.updateDefinition({title:"Updated Title"}) 
  }
}
```

I am using MaterializeCSS and its [autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) but I do not know how to use it `inside` Tabulator. And if it is actually a good idea.

Could you please suggest the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you still want to have a different auto complete per column, you just want to make the values of "contract" autocomplete dependent on the value of the "name" column.

You can pass a function into the `editorParams` option instead of an object, that function will be triggered every time the editor is opened, and should return the params object for the editor.

Using this you can make a function that will changed the `values` prop of the editor params based on the value of the name cell. in this example we will asume these values are stored in a simple contracts lookup list for a name of each user, but you can look this up however you like

```js
{title:"contract", field:"contract", editor:"autocomplete", editorParams: function(cell){
     var contracts = {
        bob:["A", "B", "C"],
        jim:["D", "E", "F"],
     };

    return {
        values: contracts[cell.getData().name] //set values list based on name cell value
    }
}},
```